# How do you describe someone who pretends to know the answer to their question after it's been answered?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I have a coworker who constantly asks questions, obvious ones and sometimes not so obvious, and always pretends to have known the answer but it accidentally slipped their mind.

*example*

> Coworker: *How do you complete this nuanced work related thing that I have never done before?*
> Me: *This is how*
> Coworker: *Oh DUH hahah oops*

Like 10 times a week

I just don’t understand why it’s so uncomfortable to just not know the answer? Isn’t that why you ask questions in the first place?

Comment: Does your coworker behaves like this to everyone or only with you? One way  to stop the coworker from interrupting your own work is to stop spoon-feeding them, and give them the manual or website where they can find the answer. Do this each and every single time and they will, eventually, get bored or  frustrated they will stop coming to you "ten times a week".

Comment: The answer may depend on why the co-worker is doing this. It could be that they're insecure about revealing their lack of knowledge.

Comment: You got the nail on the head. It is insecurity and imposter syndrome but it’s not really a syndrome when they kind of are one…

Comment: It sounds to me like they're unsure of themself. After they get the answer, it becomes obvious, so they apoligize.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a mutation of that ubiquitous workspace specie, the "*know-it-all*"...

A safe description of that personality -- and by 'safe', I mean one that would not trigger Defcon 5 in HR, if the term went down the wrong branch of the office grapevine -- would be "*pretentious*".

Have a nice day :)

[pretentious](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pretentious)

Comment: Except it stems more from lack of confidence/ actual knowledge as opposed to the perception of actually being knowledgeable

Comment: A know-it-all is someone who answers excessively, not someone who asks questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can call them

> faux-expert

or if you want to sound geeky

> pseudo-know-it-all

Comment: Is "Answer-Pretender" a term that anyone uses?

Comment: A faux-expert wouldn't ask the question in the first place, they'd claim to know how to do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).